# Column of original data is returning length as 0 in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working in R studio and trying to create a table. The error I keep getting is "Error in table(players, fitmod1$classification) : all arguments must have the same length". When I check the length of my data, fitmod1$classification is returning a value; but players is returning 0. I have no idea how to fix this.

Player's is a qualitative column of the Hitters data in R package ISLR. fitmod1 is a mclust model. I am attaching my code below so hopefully that helps! Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxoy0.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In future questions, please provide actual code with data to reproduce the issue instead of providing pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the players are the row names and not an actual column of the data. So when you subset the Hitter's data frame with:

```
players <- Hitters[,0]
```

you end up with an empty dataframe (though the rows are still named which what you are seeing when you view it in RStudio).

Instead you want to get the row names and store them as a vector:

```
players <- row.names(Hitters)
```

You will now be able to generate a table.

Here is all of the code (by the way it is much easier for us as a community to answer your questions if you use the code feature in stack overflow rather than attaching a png. This way we can copy and paste your code rather than having to type it by hand) :

```
library(ISLR)
library(mclust)

data(Hitters)
Hitters=Hitters[,c(1:7)]
Hitters<-na.omit(Hitters)

players <- row.names(Hitters)
fitmod1<-Mclust(Hitters, G=3, modelNames=c("VEE"))
table(players, fitmod1$classification)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I will be sure to do that next time!